# iReport JRXML Cannot be imported to JasperServer?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jasperserver

I have create report form iReport using OLAP connection and MDX query.
As a output I got .jrxml file from iReport. Now I want to schedule that report through Jasper server... So I am trying to import that .jrxml file in JasperServer.

But I am getting this error

```
The selected JRXML could not be parsed. You might have selected the wrong file.
```

I don't know what wrong.. How to import this file in JasperServer.

I am using iReport 4.6 and JasperServer 4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself.. its just the last line of the question.

I was using *iReports* version 4.6 with *JasperServer* 4.5. *JasperServer* 4.5 is not compatible with *iReports* 4.6.

I switched to *iReports* 4.5 and the problem is gone.

Comment: I would say that JasperReports Server didn't provide _forward_ compatibility with the future versions of iReport. It does have backwards compatibility with older versions of iReport.

Comment: but when I was trying to import iReport of 4.6 in JasperServer 4.5 it was giving error